# Run console hidden

Tags: vb.net, console, hidden

I'm trying to run a console window hidden while using CreateProcess(I can't use the ProcessStartInfo class because I have to run it with some other special settings)

I have tried to use the CREATE_NO_WINDOWS flag, but somehow, the console still pops up. This is the code I have:

```
Dim ProzessInfo = New Process_Information
Dim StartInfo = New Startup_Information, PS = New Security_Flags, TS = New Security_Flags

If CreateProcess(Nothing, target, PS, TS, False, PROCESS_CREATION_FLAG.CREATE_NO_WINDOW, Nothing, Nothing, StartInfo, ProzessInfo) = 0 Then MsgBox("Couln't start application")
```

What have I missed to run it hidden?

Comment: No, that's enough.  You don't give anybody a chance to help you troubleshoot this with such an inadequate snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try

```
AppwinStyle.Hide, True
```

[MSDN AppWinStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.appwinstyle.aspx)

Or

EDIT:
Try This for Processes

```
Dim psi1 As New ProcessStartInfo("file path here")
Process.CreateNoWindow = True
```

Depending on what your end goal is you can always change the application type to Windows Forms Application. (Assuming you are running a console app now.)

Comment: But this API can only be used if I would use the "Shell" function

Comment: Are you running a console app? I guess if you want to hide all windows you can change the type to forms. Or is this not what you are after?

Comment: Looks nice but can I also use the Startup_Info and Process_Information of CreateProcess in this method? Oh, and yey, I'm running a console app

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in the Main of your app. It will hide the console window.

```
Private Declare Auto Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
    Private Declare Auto Function GetConsoleWindow Lib "kernel32.dll" () As IntPtr

    Sub Main()
        Dim hWndConsole As IntPtr
        hWndConsole = GetConsoleWindow()
        ShowWindow(hWndConsole, False)
        rem Do your stuff here....
    End Sub
```

`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).